# Get the number of a specific class from a parent jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this structure on a online website:

```js
<div class="main">
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to find the number of `.child-two` in the base div using pure jquery, preferably using the structure: `$(selector).someFunction()`.

I already tried these:

```js
$('.main .child-two').length; //does not work -> undefined
$('.main').find('.child'); // does not work -> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find is not a function
```

Which do not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the complete code including the ``script``. Or link to a fiddle

Comment: @MajedBadawi This is the complete code?

Comment: Where are you writing the js part?

Comment: ``$('.main .child-two').length`` works fine

Comment: @MajedBadawi on the chrome debug console, to then transpile it to nodejs.

Comment: Try writing it at the bottom of your body in a ``<script>`` tag

Comment: The most likely cause is not having jQuery referenced in your file. SEe this fiddle where it works: https://jsfiddle.net/0hs1w9ke/   and remove jquery ref and you get undefined

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have include `jQuery` on your main directory, and this *code* `$('.main .child-two').length` which you are provided works perfectly fine. You can try this either `jQuery` or `javaScript` Thanks.

***e.g.***

```js
/* JQUERY */

  console.log($('.main .child-two').length);
  
/* JAVASCRIPT  */  

  var parent = document.querySelector(".main").children;

  parent[2].innerHTML = "Hello World"; // examples
  parent[2].classList.add("active"); // examples
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
</div>
```